# Using LINQ SelectMany() to join multiple child tables without a navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-core-3.1

I kind of got confused on how to achieve what I want, and after searching in the internet, I think `SelectMany()` is the way to go, but I am getting lost on how to make this work (*I have very weak understanding of how lambda expressions work I think*)..

My goal is to be able to use LINQ to populate this class:

```
public class AttendanceList
{
    public int AttendancePeriodId { get; set; }     // from AttendancePeriod class
    public int Activity { get; set; }               // from DailyAttendance class
    public string Name { get; set; }                // from Employee class
    public string Position { get; set; }            // from Employee class
    public string Department { get; set; }          // from Employee class
}
```

I have a totally wrong and non-working code, but to illustrate, I wanna use something like:

```
var query = context.AttendancePeriod
    .Include(i => i.DailyAttendance)
    .Include(i => i.DailyAttendance).ThenInclude(ii => ii.Employee)
    .Select(s => new AttendanceList
    {
        AttendancePeriodId = s.Id,
        Activity = ...,
        Name = ...,
        Position = ...,
        Department = ...
    });
```

How do I use `SelectMany()` to achieve the above?

For reference, these are my classes:

```
public class AttendancePeriod
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DailyAttendance> DailyAttendances { get; set; }
}

public class DailyAttendance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeIn { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeOut { get; set; }
    public string Activity { get; set;}
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this

First step get a flat list of all `DailyAttendances`

```
.SelectMany(x => x.DailyAttendances)
```

Now `transform` those into `AttendanceList`

```
.Select(x => new AttendanceList
{
    //x is of type `DailyAttendance`

    AttendancePeriodId = x.AttendancePeriod.Id,
    Activity = x.Activity,
    Name = x.Employee.Name,
    Position = x.Employee.Position,
    Department = x.Employee.Department,
}
```

If `DailyAttendance` doesn't have a member for `AttendancePeriod` you could do the following, instead of

```
.SelectMany(x => x.DailyAttendances)
```

use this, this will create a tuple contains x = AttendancePeriod and y = DailyAttendance

```
.SelectMany(x => x.DailyAttendances.Select(y => (x, y))
```

and now `transform` it to this

```
.Select(x => new AttendanceList
{
    //x is of type `ValueTuple<AttendancePeriod, DailyAttendance>`
    //x.Item1 is of type AttendancePeriod
    //x.Item2 is of type DailyAttendance

    AttendancePeriodId = x.Item1.Id,
    Activity = x.Item2.Activity,
    Name = x.Item2.Employee.Name,
    Position = x.Item2.Employee.Position,
    Department = x.Item2.Employee.Department,
}
```

Comment: _project_ not _transform_ :)

Comment: @ChrisSchaller - but I like the movie Transformer :D

Comment: In that case, I dub you "Rand Random the Transformer"

Comment: Thank you @RandRandom...Wow! I did not know you can do this with lambda...I'm learning new things

Answer (score 3):

Untested and without any null checking:

```
var query = context.AttendancePeriod
  // .Include(i => i.DailyAttendance)  
  // .Include(i => i.DailyAttendance).ThenInclude(ii => ii.Employee)
   .SelectMany(s => s.DailyAttendances.Select(a => 
      new AttendanceList
      {
          AttendancePeriodId = s.Id,
          Activity = a.Activity ,
          Name = a.Employee.Name,
          Position = a.Employee.Position,
          Department = a.Employee.Department,
      }));
```

Comment: remove the _implied Include_ sometimes they have no negative effect, but they duplicate entries in the expression table and are simply not necessary.

Comment: Remove Includes and query will be perfect.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv is correct, in this particular query the includes have zero effect. Includes are only used in queries that do NOT have projections. Once a projection is used, then includes are ignored.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller, actually they not always ignored. But in this case - completely.